# Scale div to background-image height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a page using a background-image.
`background-size` is set to `cover`.

The content is just a heading and two buttons.
I want the div to be always the proportional height fitting to the background.

What's the best way to do this (if possible with pure CSS)?

Comment: tried: `backround-size: 100% 100%;` ?

Comment: yes, it doesn't scale the div.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail as to what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Post the css code of your page please

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean either, but I think I might. The background size is set to cover for the entire page, so it fits the entire page. It seems you want a div inside to also fit the entire page, then, since it needs to be the same size is that background. Setting the div position to absolute, and the left, right, bottom, and top to zero, will accomplish this. But, I can't call this an answer because I'm not entirely sure if this assumption is correct. Perhaps a jsFiddle would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one same image file for both background and inline, and set the inline image to `visibility: hidden;` (keep space), so the div can automatically resize based on the image size.

There is no way to detect the background image size with CSS.

```css
.container {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/600/150?image=0") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Hello</div>
  <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/600/150?image=0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

know this is old thread but stumbled upon it.

the following works for me if i know the dimensions of the image,

eg. 1220x404 => 1220/404 = 3.01980198 = 30.1980198

```
header { max-height: 404px; height: 30.1980198vw; }
```