# Header height to fit background image

Tags: css, html

I have a question related to header height.

HTML:

```
<header>
        <h1>
            Hello World!
        </h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-image: url("../images/header.png");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

In this case header height fits text height. Is there a way to set header height the same as image height?

Comment: Yes. The same as it is naturally (not stretched).

Comment: If you know the image Height  then set the font-size property to that value. Also, make sure that vertical padding and margin of h1 element are set to 0 and vertical-align: center. Best regards,

Comment: I would like to reach a similar result to: `img {width: 100%; height: auto;}`

Comment: Yes, simmilar like that!

Comment: The link you posted has `height: 100%`. It makes the header the height of the window, not the image.

Comment: But for me it doesn't fit neither screen nor image...

Comment: See if this help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30489501/483779

Answer (score 2):

You could do the header image as a foreground img tag rather than background image and then do this in the CSS

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this way seems not to be the most elegant way... Look at the webpage: http://www.jeroenvanhaeverbeke.be/en/. There is no <img> tags and background image fits size...

Answer (score 1):

In the header's css, you can put:

```
background: url("../images/header.png") 50% 50% / 100% no-repeat fixed;
```

It will automatically place and size the image so it's not stretched.

Comment: Or `background: url("../images/header.png") no-repeat center;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Flexbox?  It's the defacto standard these days.

Here is a jsfiddle what I have in mind:
[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/728ruw9q/5/)

Essentially, what you want to do is your `<h>` element should actually be a child of another div within your `<header>`:

```
<header>
    <div class="backimage">
        <h1>
            Hello World!
        </h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Your `<header>` div, as the flex "container", display child elements as column, without wrap, aligned in the center with space around, and justified center:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-around;
}
```

Child elements within the flex "container" should be ordered for number of appearance either as a row or column, in this case the "container" displays items in a column layout, so you want your header to appear as the first item.  `flex` is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`; this third one being what size the element should be, the first two controlling what priority or portion of the container element this child element will be treated as compared to other children.  In this case, handle it auto.  We want to reposition the header to be vertically centered in the containing div, so `position: relative;`, add 50% of the container's height to the origin point of the ` element's origin (which always starts from the top left of an object), and because the text default is set at 1em, it would logically follow that .5em would be the center, so subtract that from the 50%.  Give it text-align center for horizontal centering:

```
    header h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        text-align: center;
        order: 1;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

Then you just have to worry about your background.  Background, no repeat, define the height of the image (which in this case will be applied to the div itself), border here for example just so you can see the boundary of the div, and *don't* forget that this should appear second compared to the header:

```
.backimage {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/  \
    commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    order:2;
}
```

Here's what you end up with:
[image: Example]

Here's a great guide on flexbox usage:
[Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)