# Why does min-height act like max-height?

Tags: css, bulma

On my page, I want to have a hero section with an image(a gif) and I want it to have the same width(100% of the page) but an adjustable height(as I resize my window).

But for some reason, the height of my image goes a maximum of 400px (which is also my min-height), which leads to a stretched image like:

[image]

Here is my code, (uses Bulma):

```css
.hero {
  background: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*XI3beonBnOwp-y5BwNOqCw.gif");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  min-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar is-info is-fixed-top">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="navbar-brand" style="flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center;">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io" >
        <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/narutofanon/images/c/cc/Fdl-logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130812063152">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="hero is-large has-text-centered">
  </section>
</body>
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE :
https://jsfiddle.net/8xjtknaf/2/

Is there any way, I can avoid setting a min-height value because it just feels hacky. Is there a proper way for my code to detect the size of my image and scale accordingly?

Comment: You can use with `background-size: cover;` the height property like this `height: 100vh;` .

Comment: For the height part, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489501/483779) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/483779) for possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

After you've checked @xRdev_38's comment, you might wanted to fit the image on the current screen without scrollbar.

```css
.hero1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.hero1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar is-info is-fixed-top">
        <div class="container has-text-centered">
          <div class="navbar-brand" style="flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center;">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io" >
            <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/narutofanon/images/c/cc/Fdl-logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130812063152">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="hero1">
        <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*XI3beonBnOwp-y5BwNOqCw.gif" alt="">
    </section>
  </body>
```

Check out `object-fit` and `overflow` in CSS. `object-fit: cover` provides your `img` to fit on the screen perfectly. And `overflow: hidden` removes `img`'s edges that outside of the screen.

And Personally, I do not recommend using `background-image` unless if you really need it. It's going to be hard to give values like in this case.

Also, [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) article would help you to understand about CSS length units.